# How to initialize realm object with `new` operator

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I make `Person` class and set some useful methods.

I want to save `Person` objects to realm-js, and in some situation also want to use not saved, just temporary `Person` object.

But, when I try to initialize with `new` operator, it is failed with message `Error: RealmObject cannot be called as a function`.

Is it possible to create object with `new`,
or I can only call `realm.create('Person', {...})` to create an instance (that is saddly saved to realm)?

```
class Person extends Realm.Object {
  get fullName() {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }

  // ...other useful methods
}

Person.schema = {
  name: 'Person',
  properties: {
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string'
  }
}

// Error: RealmObject cannot be called as a function
var person = new Person()
```

Note:
`extends Realm.Object` is necessary because calls of  `person.isValid()` with saved objects is important.

Comment: You have to use `create`. Realm objects are not common JavaScript objects as they live in the database.